# Springfox class Parameter is deprecated

Tags: swagger, springfox

In Springfox 3.0, `springfox.documentation.service.Parameter` is deprecated.

Is there a newer way of providing the parameter and its builder?

And how to provide its `default` value?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, use the `RequestParameter` for specify the `Parameter` in your Docket bean.

for its builder use `RequestParameterBuilder` class

RequestParameter can be look like this.

> ```
> private RequestParameter authorizationParameter() {
>     RequestParameterBuilder tokenBuilder = new RequestParameterBuilder();
>     tokenBuilder
>             .name("Authorization")
>             .description("access_token")
>             .required(false)
>             .in("header")
>             .accepts(Collections.singleton(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
>             .build();
>     return tokenBuilder.build();
> ```

Answer (score 5):

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
// Adding Header
RequestParameterBuilder aParameterBuilder = new RequestParameterBuilder();
aParameterBuilder.name("Cache-Control")
    .query(q -> q.defaultValue("no-cache, no-store")
        .model(modelSpecificationBuilder -> modelSpecificationBuilder.scalarModel(ScalarType.STRING)))
    .in(ParameterType.HEADER).required(true).build();

List<RequestParameter> aParameters = new ArrayList<>();
aParameters.add(aParameterBuilder.build());

return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
    .paths(PathSelectors.regex("(?!/error.*).*")).build().apiInfo(metadata())
    .globalRequestParameters(aParameters);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The swagger ui does not seem to work when you set required=true.  If you leave the fields empty and click submit instead of the fields blinking red, the page goes busy and the spinner just spins forever without ever sending anything